# Как вставить значение внешнего ключа в ячейку при совпадении значений в других ячейках

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы. В таблице номер 1 есть внешний ключ, который относится к id  в таблице номер 2. В обоих таблицах есть колонка street. Как вставить в таблицу номер 1 значение внешнего ключа (он же id из таблицы номер 2) при совпадении значений в колонке street?
Пробовал

```
         UPDATE ATTRACTIONS
         SET ATTRACTIONS("addresses_id") = ADDRESSES("id")
         WHERE ATTRACTIONS("street") = ADDRESSES("street")
         ;
```

Не работает. База - SQLlite.

Comment: В SQL имена колонок пишутся не в скобках у таблицы, а через точку. Кроме того имена используемых таблиц должны быть где то перечислены, но вот у update в разных базах данных разный синтаксис. например `update T set .. from X where ...` в postgresql или `update T join X on ... set ...` в mysql. Посмотрите документацию на синтаксис update в вашей БД

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующим образом:
UPDATE ATTRACTIONS SET addresses_id = (SELECT id FROM ADDRESSES WHERE ADDRESSES.street = ATTRACTIONS.street)
Проблема синтаксиса Sqllite3